# CSS Animation - Height anchor point

Tags: css, animation

New to coding here. I'm practicing with CSS, and I'm trying to create a simple animation. The twist: I want the height of a div to change, but the animation anchors the height change at the top of the div, and I need it to anchor at the bottom. I've been looking around and saw the transform-origin element, but that doesn't seem to help, as it is not a transform, but a change in height. I also tried rotating the div 180degrees but that didn't work either.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.rowleteyeleft {
height: 100px; 
width: 50px; 
border-radius: 50%; 
background-color: hsl(46, 6%, 21%); 
position: relative; 
right: -70px; 
top: 70px; 
overflow:hidden;  
animation-name: blinkleft; 
animation-duration: 1s; 
animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
animation-direction:alternate;}

@keyframes blinkleft {
to {height: 10px}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="rowleteyeleft"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to add to it to get the height to anchor at the bottom?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You might include a codepen or jsfiddle for people and maybe a visual example of what you hope to accomplish vs what's wrong to help folks visualize your intent better than that description provides. Also, you keyframes css isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
.rowleteyeleft {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  right: -70px;
  top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rowleteyeleft:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: hsl(46, 6%, 21%);
  animation-name: blinkleft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes blinkleft {
  to {
    height: 10px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rowleteyeleft"></div>
```

This demo shows you what is doing on behind the animation

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 70px;
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  /*this help us animate the child from the bottom*/
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed hsl(46, 6%, 21%);
}
.rowleteyeleft {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: hsl(46, 6%, 21%);
  animation-name: blinkleft;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes blinkleft {
  to {
    height: 100px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper><!--give your animated element a parent-->
  <div class="rowleteyeleft"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is super confusing to me. What's going on? What does the :before thing do? I thought that just put content before an element.